Redirections changes "get-alias" command return code in powershell
I want test if an alias exists with the following code :
if( (get-alias ls) ) {
    echo "=> Alias ls already exists."
} else {
    echo "=> Alias ls does not exist."
}

When run, it says :

CommandType     Name                                               Version    Source
-----------     ----                                               -------    ------
Alias           ls -> Get-ChildItem


=> Alias ls already exits.

I tried to redirect the output of the command to $null :
if( (get-alias ls >$null) ) {
    echo "=> Alias ls already exits."
} else {
    echo "=> Alias ls does not exist."
}

I expected this output when run :
=> Alias ls already exists.

But the outcome of the code snippet somehow changed :
=> Alias ls does not exist.

If I redirect after the first set of parenthesis, I also get :
=> Alias ls does not exist.

Why does redirection interfere with the result?

The output is coming from some other statement in your script/code, not the if condition. Show us the whole script

If tests whether or not there's output, not the result code $? of the command.  You can combine two statements with $( ).
echo hi > foo

if (dir foo > $null) <# no result #> { 'yes' }


if ($(dir foo > $null; $?)) { 'yes' }

yes


Oh I see, I wanted to test the $? result code of the command. Thanks a lot.

Because by redirecting the Success Stream(aka stdOut) to $null nothing remains to be evaluated by if, which results into a $false detection.
You can instead use
if ( $null = Get-Alias ls -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue  ) {
    Write-Output '=> Alias ls already exists.'
}
else {
    Write-Output '=> Alias ls does not exist.'
}

This way If will evaluate if any not-false value has been stored into the associated variable, in this case $null so it gets discarded immediately
Using Get-Alias on a non-existent alias will throw an non-stopping error and return a $null.
-ErrorAction SilentlyContinue will hide the error(while still recording it into $Error), and because a $null value has been store, if will detect $false
And, of course, if Get-Alias returns a value, if will detect $true and because the value was store into $null it will be immediately destroyed.

I didn't know that = trick.  It's still based on the output.

well, yeah. But by redirecting to $null you are throwing out the results before evaluation.  Note the "= trick" works even with regular variables, so you can do, for example: if($FileList=Gci -file){ $FileList | Do-Things}else{ 'Directory is empty, sorry' }

To add to the existing, helpful answers:

Indeed - unlike in POSIX-compatible shells such as bash - PowerShell conditionals act on success-stream output from a command being tested, not its success status (as reflected in the automatic $? variable).[1]

If the output isn't already a Boolean ($true or $false), it is coerced to one, using the rules described in the about_Booleans help topic.

For instance, a command producing no output is interpreted as $false -  which may or may not correlate with the command also signaling an error condition via $? reflecting $false.



However, in PowerShell (Core) 7, the cross-platform install-on-demand edition of PowerShell, there are conditional forms that act on $?, i.e. the success status, just like in POSIX-compatible shells, from which the feature was borrowed, namely in the form of
&& and || the pipeline-chain operators:

command-a && command-b executes command-b only if command-a succeeded (if $? is $true)

command-a || command-b executes command-b only if command-a failed (emitted at least one error, in which case $? is $false)

Like their POSIX-shell counterparts, they do not consume command output and only act on the commands' success vs. failure as implied by $?

It follows that using expressions instead of commands with these operators is of limited use, as they typically do not cause errors and therefore don't cause $? to reflect $false; there are exceptions, however (but note that in the absence of try ... catch the error message cannot be suppressed):

1 / 0 || 'failed!'
[int]::Parse('NotANumber') || 'failed!'


However, a fundamental limitation is that the operators can only chain pipelines, i.e., (single) commands and expressions, and not also language statements (based on keywords),   notably including exit; to do so, use of $(...), the subexpression operator is required:

Get-Item NoSuch || exit 1 does not work, because exit is a language statement.
Get-Item NoSuch || $(exit 1) works, due to $(...)






Applied to your case:

Using && and ||:
# PowerShell 7 only.
Get-Alias ls *>$null && 'Alias exists.' || 'Alias does NOT exist.'


Note the use of redirection *>$null to suppress output from all streams, which is necessary, because, as noted, && and || by design do not quietly consume any output streams, i.e. also not the success output stream (which is what regular PowerShell conditionals quietly consume).


Using a regular if statement, as an alternative to the solutions in the other answers: You could use a Test-Path call to test the existence of an alias, via the Alias: drive published by the alias provider:
if (Test-Path Alias:ls) {
  'Alias exists.'
} else {
  'Alias does NOT exist.'
}


Test-Path only ever emits $true or $false, so there's no error output to suppress.

This works analogously for the other PowerShell providers; e.g., you can use Test-Path Function:Foo to test the existence of a Foo function, or Test-Path Env:Bar to test the existence of an environment variable named Bar.





[1] It is the counterpart of the variable of the same name in POSIX-compatible shells; however, the latter contains the exit code of the most recently executed command, whereas in PowerShell it is a Boolean:
$true indicates successful (error-free) execution, whereas $false implies that (at least one) error occurred. In the context of calls to external programs, an exit code of 0 is reflected as $true in $?, and any nonzero exit code as $false.
PowerShell-native commands do not use exit codes, but PowerShell provides the automatic $LASTEXITCODE variable to reflect the exit code of the most recently executed external program (and also of PowerShell scripts (*.ps1 files) if they use exit with a number to exit).

Using && and || seems similar to a ternary expression. (Get-Alias ls -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue) ? 'Alias exists.' : 'Alias does NOT exist.'

@lit, not quite, because the ternary conditional acts just like an if statement with respect to determining what is truthy: it tests and consumes command output; by contrast, && and || by design pass all output through, and only act on the commands' success status; I've updated the answer to clarify.

Sorry to drag this out, but why does the statement I gave appear to work; reporting that the alias exists? Is it because of the SilentlyContinue? If it was "just like an if statement", then why would the expression not result in $false?

@lit, it works just like if (Get-Alias ls -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue) { 'Alias exists.' } else { 'Alias does NOT exist.' } does: it coerces the success-stream output of Get-Alias to a Boolean, which in this case means: if there's no output, $false is implied; if there is output, and because that cmdlet's output, if present, is invariably "truthy", $true is implied. The success-stream output is quietly consumed in the process; any other streams are passed through; since a nonexistent alias causes error-stream output, -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue can be used to silence it
